# Type 'Year' is not assignable to type 'Year[]'. Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Year'

Tags: angular, angular-observable

am getting error while using angular 4 and observable.

ERROR in src/app/ca-calendar/calendar.component.ts(84,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Type 'Year' is not assignable to type 'Year[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Year'.

What am I doing wrong?

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Year, Month } from '../../models';

@Injectable()
export class CalendarService {
  endPoint: string;
  private _calendarUrl = '/api/mycalendar';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getYear(id: string): Observable<Year> {
    return this.http.get(this._calendarUrl + '?id=' + id)._catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getYears(): Observable<Year> {
    return this.http.get(this._calendarUrl)
                    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                    ._catch(this.handleError);
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MonthCalendarComponent } from './month-calendar/month-calendar.component';
import { Month } from '../models/month';
import { MonthsService } from '../services/calendar/months/months.service';
import { CalendarService } from '../services/calendar/calendar.service';
import { Year } from '../models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'ca-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css']

})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
public myYears$: Observable<Year[]>;


  constructor(private calendarService: CalendarService, private monthsService: MonthsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.myYears$ = this.calendarService.getYears();
}
```

...and Model

```
import { Month } from './month';
import { Week } from './week';

export class Year {
    id: String;
    number: Number;
    months: Month[];
    weeks: Week[];

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

Comment: In your service you return Observable<Year> from 'getYears()' but in your component you assign myYears$ as Observable<Year[]> - one of them needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Your method getYears signature is `Observable<Year>` and your variable $myYears is typed with `Observable<Year[]>`.
try to do something like that with a `Observable<Year[]>`signature for getYears method :

```
 getYears(): Observable<Year[]> {
      return this.http.get(this._calendarUrl)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .map((yearsData: any) => {
                    return yearsData.map(yearData => {
                         const year = new Year());
                         year.id = yearData.id;
                         ...
                         return year;
                    })
                })
                ._catch(this.handleError);
```

Using that method you have directly an instance of your model and you have the good signature.

Hopes it helps you.